# Add a shape to a slide and format that

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to make my vba script below to add annotation notes to powerpoint slides. The idea is that the script can be used to add "to-be-checked notes" to slides. Hence, I've got it set up in a little add-in that displays a menu so adding the TBC, TBU, TBD notes are added.
The sub is showing errors from time to time and does not always fully do its job (i guess because of the part where I wrote in my code:

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Rectangle 4").Select
```

Can anyone assist me how do make the script bulletproof. A short explanation of the approach would be great. That way I can learn how do things right in the future.

Best,

### eltiburon

This is what my entire script so far looks like:

```
Sub InsertShape_TBC()

ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 575.5, 9.12, 124.75, 34.12).Select
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.Solid
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(162, 30, 36)
    .Fill.Transparency = 0#
    .Line.Visible = msoFalse
End With
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=0).Select
With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange
    .Text = "[TBC]"
    With .Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 18
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Underline = msoFalse
        .Shadow = msoFalse
        .Emboss = msoFalse
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .AutoRotateNumbers = msoFalse
        .Color.SchemeColor = ppForeground
    End With
End With
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Rectangle 4").Select
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes("Rectangle 4").Select
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=6).Select
ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(Red:=255, Green:=255, Blue:=255)
ActivePresentation.ExtraColors.Add RGB(Red:=255, Green:=255, Blue:=255)
ActiveWindow.Selection.Unselect
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like the kind of code produced by the macro recorder in earlier versions of PPT.

First off, never select anything in code unless it's absolutely necessary to do so (and it seldom is).  Use shape references instead (as you've seen in a couple of the other examples I posted in response to your other questions).

Because the recorded macro assumes that you're working with a shape called Rectangle 4, it will only work if you run it on a slide that has three rectangles already.  So instead:

```
Dim oSh as Shape
Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 575.5, 9.12, 124.75, 34.12)
' Notice that I removed the .Select from the end of your code.  
' We don't want to select anything if we don't have to.

' Then
With oSh
   With .TextFrame.TextRange
      .Text = "[TBC]"
       With .Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 18
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Underline = msoFalse
        .Shadow = msoFalse
        .Emboss = msoFalse
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .AutoRotateNumbers = msoFalse
        .Color.SchemeColor = ppForeground
    End With   ' Font
   End with   ' TextRange
End With   ' oSh, the shape itself
```

Comment: This works good. I added some coloring myself and it works just as intented. Thank you very much. The comments are also quite useful for me to grasp the logic behind the operations performed by the macro. Thanks for those as well.

Comment: Yep, I figured it'd be a good idea to salt some extra notes in there for you.