# Powerpoint VBA - How to rotate right-angled triangle?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following VBA code, adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24512082):

```
Sub Risk(ByVal control As IRibbonControl)

    Dim tri As Shape
    Set tri = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRightTriangle, 886, 0, 74, 74)

    With tri
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)

        With .Line
        .Weight = 0
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With ' Outline

        With .TextFrame.TextRange
          .Text = "Risk"

           With .Font
            .Name = "Arial"
            .Size = 10
            .Bold = msoTrue
            .Italic = msoFalse
            .Underline = msoFalse
            .Shadow = msoFalse
            .Emboss = msoFalse
            .BaselineOffset = 0
            .AutoRotateNumbers = msoFalse
            .Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End With   ' Font

       End With   ' TextRange

    End With ' Shape itself

    End Sub
```

This successfully creates a right-angled triangle, but it's got the wrong orientation (the right angle should be flush against the corner). How do I rotate it?

---

**Note: Question was edited to incorporate comment, and made more specific.**

Comment: Start with [`Shape.Fill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.fill) and [`Shape.Line`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shape.line). You already specify the position and size in [`Shapes.AddShape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addshape).

Comment: @BigBen Thank you - I was being very stupid. I've incorporated all your suggestions - how do I rotate the shape?

Comment: A Shape has a `Rotation` property. Can you try to tinker with that?

Comment: Another hint: Shapes work much the same in Excel as they do in PowerPoint. Excel allows you to "record a macro" (basically, translates your user-interaction to VBA code). If you are stuck, that is also a good place to start. Record a macro doing the rotation manually, and then use/modify the recorded VBA code in PowerPoint. Cheers.

Comment: @DavidZemens I found the rotation property, but it rotates the text inside 180 degrees as well. How best to get around this? (and thank you for the Excel tip!)

Comment: You can also rotate the text, if I recall correctly. That's a textrange or textframe  property, I think.

Comment: Maybe `.TextFrame2.Notextrotation = msoTrue`?

Comment: @DavidZemens I'm getting an `object doesn't support this action` error when I try that.

Comment: hmmmm. I don't see an obvious or intuitive way to do this. Not particularly surprising. It's odd that the `NoTextRotation` raises an error, but I see the same error on my end even though this *should* be a valid property of the shape.

Comment: @DavidZemens Solved with `.TextFrame2.ThreeD.RotationZ = -180` but this messes with the look of the text so I'll probably just create another box.

Comment: Yes that would be the other hack -- creating a separate textbox that overlays or is a child shape of your triangle.